# How to modify fiber reinforced actuator FEA modelling?

Tags: abaqus

After successfully duplicating the [fibre-reinforced actuator](https://softroboticstoolkit.com/book/fr-modeling) I want to change the design to add another layer of elastosil tube and another layer of fiber to look something like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uxGob.jpg) (excluding the caps). These are the steps that outline my methodology however I am not sure if my approach is correct

1. Inner First Circle
2. Inner Second Circle
3. Extrude
4. Outer First Circle
5. Outer second Circle
6. Extrude
7. adding tube I as an instance
8. adding tube II as an instance
9. merging instances to make merged actuator
10. create point for fiber I
11. running fibers script (to make helix)
12. create point for fiber II
13. running fibers script (to make helix II)
14. Add fibers I and II to assembly
15. adding fiber I and II instance
16. DEFINE elastosil material
17. DEFINE kevlar material
18. creating elastosil sections (for tube I)
19. creating elastosil section II (for tube II)
20. creating kevlar/fiber section (for fiber I)
21. creating kevlar/fiber section II (for fiber II)
22. assigning sections for merged actuator
23. assigning sections for fibers
24. beam section orientation for fiber I and II
25. create inner surface for tube I
26. create outer surface for tube II
27. create step
28. Boundary conditions (??????)
29. Amplitude
30. Apply load
31. mesh control
32. mesh element type
33. set seed
34. mesh generation
35. mesh fibers
36. mesh settings for fibers
37. mesh
38. tie constraint for fiber I and tube II (inner surface)
39. tie constraint for tube II (outer surface) and fiber II

Any recommendations are appreciated

Answer (score 0):

I think the steps you have mentioned should help you model the actuator that you have shown in the image.